# Building MacOSX Frameworks with CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build an OS X library using CMake. This libary also includes some amount of resource files (.pdfs used as icon images). In my initial attempts, I have been building the library and the resource files separately as libGeneric.a and generic-Resources.bundle - with, the bundle hosting all the relevant images that libGeneric.a uses.

```
set (SRC srcfile1.m srcfile2.m)
set (HEADERS srcfile1.h srcfile2.h)
set (ICONS icon1.pdf icon2.pdf)
set (SOURCE_FILE_PROPERTIES ${ICONS} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION "Resources")
add_library(generic ${SRC} ${HEADERS})
add_library(generic-Resources MODULE ${ICONS})
set_target_properties(generic-Resources PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C) # to suppress CMake error of not able to determine linker language for libary
set_target_properties(generic-Resources PROPERTIES BUNDLE TRUE)
```

This worked fine, except, I was not able to figure out how to directly include the .bundle in the build process of applications that was using libGeneric.a. The only way I could get CMake to load the bundle was to add it as a source file in the target application. But, since, the bundle had not yet been compiled while running CMake, it would complain that the source file did not exist. As a workaround, I resorted to manually adding the .bundle into xcode after CMake generated the App.xcodeproj file (and I actually compiled the bundle). As this was getting to be cumbersome, I figured I'd try to build a Mac OS X framework instead (to house both the library and the code)

```
set (SRC srcfile1.m srcfile2.m)
set (HEADERS srcfile1.h srcfile2.h)
set (ICONS icon1.pdf icon2.pdf)
set (SOURCE_FILE_PROPERTIES ${ICONS} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION "Resources")
add_library(generic SHARED ${SRC} ${HEADERS} ${ICONS})
set_target_properties(generic PROPERTIES FRAMEWORK TRUE)
set_target_properties(generic PROPERTIES MACOSX_RPATH TRUE) #to suppress cmake warnings on rpath
```

However, this is creating a framework with just the Icons inside a Resources directory. The code library is missing. I would appreciate some assistance in getting this framework to build correctly. How, do I

- get CMake to actually build a library with the indicated source file
  and place it inside the framework
- get CMake to copy the headers appropriately in the framework.
- I am just setting rpath to true now, as I haven't really figured out what to actually do with it. What do I set this to? The objective is to build a private framework, that I would then bundle automatically with my application.

  Alternatively, is there an easy way to get CMake to build the bundle file created in my earlier process, and then load that built file into my applications build process.